# Prove inequality polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Under the following condition $1\geq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left | {\frac{a_i}{a_n}} \right |$
how i can i prove that $\left | x \right |\leq 1$, considering the polynomial x $\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^{i}$, $a_n\neq 0$ and $p(x)=0$? I already tried an inductive argument, but i can't seem to arrive at something useful.

Comment: by contradiction, if $|x|>1$, can you bound the polynomial minus the leading term?

Comment: Could you give me another hint, i don't quite see it yet?